# ObjectOutputStream not writing to file

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to serialize an object to file with the following:

```
// fill with some test data 
ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
transactions.add(new Transaction("Internet", "2016-09-20", -28));
transactions.add(new Transaction("Groceries", "2016-09-20", -26));

//serialize transactions 
try {
//          File f = new File("transactions.ser");
//          OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(f);
//          OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
//          ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

    File f = new File("transactions.ser");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    out.writeObject(transactions);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object o = in.readObject();
    System.out.println(o);

} 
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("IOException");
} 
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
}
```

..however the IOException is being thrown. The code that is commented out does manage to create the file, but it was empty, so I assume that it's not a permissions issue? After some reading I found ObjectOutputStream but won't write to the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well you're currently swallowing the exception and just printing `IOException`. Print out the exception itself and it will tell you what's wrong. Note that you should also be using try-with-resources to handle the closing...

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("IOException")` use `e.printStackTrace()`. Please [edit] the question and add the resulting stack trace, properly formatted. The stack trace is the first place to look when you have an exception - don't suppress it with a meaningless print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verify that your class **Transaction** implements `Serializable` , you may have a type exception `java.io.NotSerializableException`

I tried your code and the error that I concluded was that it did not implement the `Serializable` interface because without this could **not convert your objects to bytes and then write them to a file**

```
public class Transaction implements Serializable{...}
```

Comment: While this could be cause of OP problem, please don't post guesses as answers (we have comments section to ask OP for more info if it is needed to provide proper answer). If it is not a guess then please provide clarification why you are sure that this is the problem so OP and others could learn how to analyze this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Good observation, to consider

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.crone.core;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Crunchify {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int i;
        Item item = new Item();
        List<Item> obj;
        obj = new ArrayList<Item>();


        obj.add(new Item("Item1101","ipad",499,1));
        obj.add(new Item("Item1102","iphone",599,3));
        // Let's serialize an Object
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./Crunchify_Test1.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(obj);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("\nSerialization Successful... Checkout your specified output file..\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Let's deserialize an Object
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("./Crunchify_Test1.txt");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            System.out.println("Deserialized Data: \n" + in.readObject().toString());
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

 class Item implements Serializable {

    private String itemID;
    private String desc;
    private double cost;
    private int quantity;

    public Item() {
        itemID = "";
        desc = "";
        cost = 0;
        quantity = 0;
    }

    public Item(String id, String d, double c, int q) {
        itemID = id;
        desc = d;
        cost = c;
        quantity = q;

    }

    /**
     * @return the itemID
     */
    public String getItemID() {
        return itemID;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemID
     *            the itemID to set
     */
    public void setItemID(String itemID) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the desc
     */
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    /**
     * @param desc
     *            the desc to set
     */
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cost
     */
    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    /**
     * @param cost
     *            the cost to set
     */
    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    /**
     * @return the quantity
     */
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    /**
     * @param quantity
     *            the quantity to set
     */
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    /*
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [itemID=" + itemID + ", desc=" + desc + ", cost=" + cost + ", quantity=" + quantity + "]";
    }

}
```

This might help you!